# Merge PHP arrays into key value pairs

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

I have 4 arrays which I would like to merge into one array with key value pairs.

This is what the arrays looks like right now

```
$id = [
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5
];

$person = [
    45,
    12,
    47,
    23,
    11
];
$date = [
    '2016-01-01', 
    '2016-01-02', 
    '2016-01-03', 
    '2016-01-04', 
    '2016-01-05'
];

$duration = [
    12,
    23,
    46,
    67,
    78
];

$type = [
    3,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    2
];
```

And I want it to look like this

```
$data = [
 'id' => value,
 'person' => value,
 'date' => value,
 'duration' => value,
 'type' => value,
];
```

As you can se every array contains 1153 items and each index have a relation with the same index in the other arrays.

How do I do this?

Comment: how are you outputting the first codeblock?

Comment: @PhpDude I updated the example to make it easier to read.

Comment: So do a `foreach` and take elements with same key.

Comment: And what is `value` in the result array?

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over one of your arrays and add to `$data` items with same index (`$key`) as current iterated element:

```
$data = [];
foreach ($id as $key => $value) {
    $data[] = [
      'id' => $value,
      'person' => $person[$key],
      'date' => $date[$key],
      'duration' => $duration[$key],
      'type' => $type[$key],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it.

```
    $data = [];
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($id); $i++) {
        $data[] = [
          'id' => $id[$i],
          'person' => $person[$i],
          'date' => $date[$i],
          'duration' => $duration[$i],
          'type' => $type[$i],
        ];
    }
```